# otrs as requester with invoker event "TicketSlaveLinkAdd"

Tags: otrs

**My situation:**

- I create via OTRS Admin Backend a custom webservice:REST
- added an custom invoker on GenericInterface::Invoker::ModuleRegistration
- added new invoker:REST Event-Trigger: TicketSlaveLinkAdd
- configured otrs as requester HTTP::REST Host as: http://myhost.com
- controller mapping: /LinkAdd/:TicketID
- standard command: PATCH

**My Problem:**

System Log returns:

> DebugLog error: Summary: HTTP::REST Error while determine Operation for request URI '/LinkAdd'. Data : No data provided.
>
> DebugLog error: Summary: Request could not be processed Data : HTTP::REST Error while determine Operation for request URI '/LinkAdd'..
>
> DebugLog error: Summary: Returning provider data to remote system (HTTP Code: 500) Data : HTTP::REST Error while determine Operation for request URI '/LinkAdd'..

Maybe somebody know about my problem and can help :)

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `Error while determine Operation` text points out that OTRS is the incoming call is not able to determine the Operation for the incoming URI; please check your data mapping.